# Android- On clicking button the message sending does not stop

Tags: android, android-gps, android-sms

I am trying to build an app where I share my location via text message. In the `activity` I have one `button` and one `TextView`. After clicking the `button` the `text message` is sent to the specified number provided. The problem is that once I click the `button`, the `message` sending does not stop unless I uninstall the application. In one go it sends around 30-40 text messages. The code is given below :

**Gps4Activity.java**

```
public class Gps4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesAPIActivity";
private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;
private TextView display1,display2,display3,display4,display5;
private Button button;
String number="+91xxxxxxxxxx";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps4);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showL);
    display1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location2);
    display2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location3);
    display3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location4);
    display4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location5);
    display5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location6);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Gps4Activity.this)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .build();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Gps4Activity.this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gps4Activity.this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Gps4Activity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                } else {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callPlaceDetectionApi();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            break;

    }
}

private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                "likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
display2.setText(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString(),
                        null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to check for the number of messages sent. I just want one `text message` to be sent on `button` click.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending message for multiple places, Instead, you can take the best match and send only one message like this or Just break the loop once you send the message.

```
    private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                //Edited
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                    "likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                    display2.setText(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString(),
                            null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
//                if(likelyPlaces != null && likelyPlaces.get(0) != null) {
//                    PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood = likelyPlaces.get(0);
//                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
//                                    "likelihood: %g",
//                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
//                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
//                    display2.setText(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString());
//                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
//                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress().toString(),
//                            null, null);
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
//                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    likelyPlaces.release();
//                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The code which you gave crashes and throws an `exception`, but the putting the break after I send the message works. Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it happening because the likelyPlaces can contain many place, and you put the sms method inside the likelyPlaces loop. Thus, it will send sms for every likelyPlaces data. If it contains 40 places, it will send it 40 times.

Comment: So any idea on what should I do? Like I tried creating a seperate method to send the text message, but still does not work

Comment: If you just want to send an sms, just put break; under Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to send text message only one number;

```
 private void sendMySMS(String personalPhone, String messege)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(messege);
    for (String msg : messages)
    {
        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
        sms.sendTextMessage(personalPhone, null, msg, sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: can I use `getApplicationContext()` in place of `getActivity()` ?

Comment: Yes ....getActivity will use in fragment...For an activity u have to use getApplicationContext()

Comment: Please upvote and tick my question if it is really helpful to u

Comment: Itr does not work!!!, My problem is that when I click on the button , it keeps on sending message to the sepecified number, and unless I delete the app it keeps on sending the message and does not stop. I need to send only ONE text message to the specified number

Comment: @PritomMazumdar check my answer.

Comment: put your send message code only in button's on click event......and first u have to get your location url and after getting that jst pass that url as a string in send message function